# Casting a rvalue reference parameter to a rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, rvalue-reference

I'm currently trying to implement a really small nested exception mechanism in my code, as `std::nested_exception`s aren't available for all the compilers I must compile my code with.

I came across the following useful nesting wrapper in the [gcc implementation source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01326_source.html):

```
template<typename _Except>
struct _Nested_exception : public _Except, public nested_exception
{
    explicit _Nested_exception(_Except&& __ex)
    : _Except(static_cast<_Except&&>(__ex))
    { }
};
```

which allows to combine an exception that has been thrown with the `nested_exception` class in `throw_with_nested` so that one can `dynamic_cast` to test whether the exception we've caught is actually a nested exception or not later on.

What I don't understand is the `static_cast` here. I think I'm missing something about move-semantics, is it really needed?

Comment: The `static_cast` is effectively equivalent to a `forward<_Except>(__ex)`

Comment: @Columbo yes, but this is not an example of perfect forwarding because the type of `__ex` will never be deduced. This is more like `std::move(__ex)`.

Comment: @jepio Whether or not `_Except` was deduced is irrelevant - my statement is valid nonetheless. And no one has mentioned perfect forwarding.

Comment: @Columbo it's valid and hence why I wrote __yes, but...__. `forward` is meant to be used for _perfect forwarding_ so you implicitly mentioned it. The semantics of that cast is that of a call to `std::move`, which for rvalues is the same as `std::forward`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `__ex` is an `_Except&&`, once you enter this scope `__ex` is an lvalue - it's a local variable. To enforce the use of the move constructor inside of `_Except` they do `_Except(static_cast<_Except&&>(__ex))` to force `__ex` to become an rvalue (it's probably actually an xvalue).

Comment: I see, I think I've seen that mentioned somewhere but forgot about it as I don't use move-semantics that much, that as soon as we enter the function, it's named and thus an lvalue. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clearer: the rvalue parameter type means the original value that got passed in is passed as rvalue, but in the function, the variable __ex is a lvalue. You can cast or preferably use `std::move` (although it is usually implemented as a cast)

Answer (score 2):

Move semantics means that we know that this constructor has been called with a parameter that is a temporary (or to-be-moved-from object). We see this in the type of `__ex` which is `_Except&&`. However if we were to use `__ex` within this constructor it would be treated as an lvalue - it clearly has a name and we can take it's address.

If you want to pass `__ex` to any further functions/constructors, it's rvalue-ness needs to be restored. The normal way to do so is by calling `std::move(__ex)` which will reapply `&&` to the type of `__ex`. This is really just the same `static_cast` that you see above.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I forgot that a `move` doesn't move and is actually a cast. Should've thought of that...

Comment: `reaply &&` is not a good term to use... Maybe should say `cast type T to T&&`